# It does not add in my database, the code seems right though

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I add an employee but then I can update and delete.

Please help me.

[image]

my database oic for reference is below

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wxWmFawOYfOTYz3e7Vl0MoHUsOFPBY1A

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, particularly the topics under the Asking section.

Comment: ask specific question please.

Comment: when I click the add, the values I inserted doesn't insert to my table. the link above is my code

Comment: post code HERE not a zip file on some host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[you can refer how to set the attribute of the column at the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22OBI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you don't input the middle name when you save the new data.
so you have to set for "middlename" column to allow Null.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `personal_info` (
  `personal_info_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `middlename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` binary(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`personal_info_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8